# Access a member function using QQuickWindow

Tags: qt, qml, qimage

I have set ObjectName to a class in main and want to access this object from another class:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
   ImageProvider *imageProvider = new ImageProvider(&engine,QQmlImageProviderBase::Image,0);
   PageBuffer p;
   p.setObjectName("Object"); 
   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("p",&p);
   engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
   engine.addImageProvider("images", imageProvider);

return app.exec();
}
```

The class where i am trying to access PageBuffer p from:

```
QImage ImageProvider ::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
 {
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(m_engine->rootObjects()[0]);
    PageBuffer *p = window->findChild<PageBuffer *>("Object");
    cout<<p->current_box; //error at runtime
    QImage e;
    e.load("Pic4.jpg");
    return e; 
 }
```

But i cant seem to access any member of the object PageBuffer, maybe because of pointers, how can can i access the functions from the object p?

Comment: Is `p` actually a valid pointer and not null?

Comment: Yes it is NULL i just checked, that means i dint get the right object from QQuickWindow

Comment: I also checked that the p instance is not the child as i printed alll the Object names of each child in the QQuickWindow it doesnt show the specified one which i set in main function for the instance p

Answer (score 0):

You could just introduce a `pageBuffer` member to `ImageProvider`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    ImageProvider *imageProvider = new ImageProvider(&engine,QQmlImageProviderBase::Image,0);
    PageBuffer p;
    imageProvider->setPageBuffer(p);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    engine.addImageProvider("images", imageProvider);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Then you don't need to search for object children, you can access `pageBuffer` directly:

```
QImage ImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(m_engine->rootObjects()[0]);
    PageBuffer *p = pageBuffer();
    cout << p->current_box;
    QImage e;
    e.load("Pic4.jpg");
    return e; 
}
```

Comment: This p object will be updated in QML , it will be the same instance in the imageprovider class right?

Comment: Yep: `Q_PROPERTY(PageBuffer *pageBuffer READ // etc ...)`

Comment: Yeh thanks a lot! , it works without setting property